# Mono Android tracking application unexpected crashing background

Tags: android, background, mono, gps, location

We are currently in the testing phase of a simple mono for android location tracking app.  The application selects an ‘entity’ to monitor and fires up a service inheriting the ILocationListener class.  We use a simple timer object to send lat/long information to a Web API service every 3 seconds.  The app will then sit in the background on the phone and track location information from GPS behind the scenes.

The issue we are having is that after an undetermined amount of time (sometimes 15 min, sometimes 8 hours) the application simply stops tracking in the background and we are having a real hard time finding the reason why.  When opening the application the behaviour can vary, in some instances the application simply restarts itself, other instances a black screen is presented as if the UI has stalled.  Our current testing device is the Samsung Galaxy 3 but we have also used the Samsung Ace 2 with same results.

The code below is the background tracking code in a nut shell.  We have not been able to obtain the actual error details which is making this error very tricky.  If I find any further information regarding why it crashes in background whether that be memory issue or UI stall I will provide.

```
public override void OnCreate()
{
        base.OnCreate();
        BusTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(3000);
        BusTimer.Elapsed += OnTimeEvent;
        isTracking = false;
        StartTracking();
        BusTimer.Start();
}

public void StartTracking()
{

        if (SystemProperties.EntityTrackingID == 0 && SystemProperties.EntityTrackingType != "Track Me")
        {
            return;
        }
        isTracking = true;

        //SETUP THE LOCATION VARIALBES
        if (_geocoder == null) { 
            _geocoder = new Geocoder(this); 
        }

        if (_locationManager == null)
        {
            _locationManager = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(LocationService);
        }

        var criteria = new Criteria() { Accuracy = Accuracy.Fine };
        string bestProvider = _locationManager.GetBestProvider(criteria, true);
        currentLocation = _locationManager.GetLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
        _locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 3000, 1, this);
}

private void OnTimeEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
        //LOG RECORD FOR CURRENT LOCATION
        if (currentLocation != null && isTracking)
        {
             PostData(currentLocation, DateTime.Now);
        }    
}
```